# What kind of wire is this and is it safe to leave cut like this?

Tags: electrical, cables

A previous homeowner had cut this cable and left it sticking out of the floor (with a caddy surrounding it).  Unfortunately I am unable to trace it in our drop ceiling in the basement because it's running between venting and the subfloor.  What kind of wire is this, and is it safe to push back through the hole and just ignore it or do we need to do something to handle it properly?

[image: white casing with greyish blue insulation and a copper wire surrounded by white padding maybe?]

white casing with greyish blue insulation and a copper wire surrounded by white padding maybe?  Home was built in the 70s, but this was fed through flooring that was laid over existing floor sometime after construction.

Comment: Is this a Rorschach test? I see a cable television cable.

Comment: Picture is fuzzy but your description sounds like your basic coax cable.  Either from roof top antenna or cable company

Comment: why did you include such a bad picture? ... what prevented you from checking the quality of the picture and taking another one?

Comment: @jsotola I suppose because people will happily upvote and answer such posts. So if all you want is an answer (to frame it nicely), and you get it almost immediately with a reward on top... then why expend any more effort?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Coaxial cable, typically used for cable TV. It's safe the leave or push back into the hole.

Not sure why they would have parked a Cadillac on it.

Comment: Pretty sure "caddy" is only commonly used to refer to Cadillac in one or two of the English-speaking countries of the world.

Answer (score 3):

It's a TV or sat dish cable.  If it is part of a distribution network in your house, cutting and leaving it open may cause ghost images for other TV viewers who might get angry.  In that respect, it isn't safe.  It would make sense tracing the cable to the respective distribution point and putting a line terminator there.

If you are the only potential user on that antenna, it doesn't really matter, assuming the installation is done properly (like, with regard to lightning protection if there is burnable material around).